# C++ Generating random numbers

Tags: c++, random, numbers

```
srand(time(NULL));
    for (int o = 0; o < 8; o++){

        x = rand() % 126 + 33;      
        keysInNumbers[o] = x;
        cout << "Randomly generated number: " << keysInNumbers[o] << endl;
    };
```

This should be generating random numbers between 33 and 126 but for some reason there are a few numbers that are above 126 though never below 33. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Look at C++11's `<random>`.

Comment: `rand() % 126` can be anything up to 125. Then you add 33.

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers will go up to (not including) *126+33*, which by my calculations is 159.

It's basic logic, really. `rand() % 126` will go up to (not including) 126 … and then you add 33!

I guess you meant `x = (rand() % (126-33)) + 33`.

In addition, you should:

- get rid of those "magic numbers";
- not use '%' as the distribution is very poor;
- research C++'s built-in random number generation features (as opposed to C's).

Comment: "x = (rand() % 126-33) + 33" This would generate numbers below 33 wouldn't it? Will check the random number generation features you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, you initially did not have 2 brackets around 126-33 which would've just meant 126. My mistake, did not pick up on that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate a random uniform distribution with

```
int A = 33;
int B = 126;
auto myrand = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<>(A,B), std::mt19937(std::random_device()()));

for (int o = 0; o < 8; o++){

    x = myrand();      
    keysInNumbers[o] = x;
    cout << "Randomly generated number: " << keysInNumbers[o] << endl;
};
```

This will use the random source if available on system to seed.